Vector3.move_toward(Vector3,delta) is not working, Godot 3d
I wanted the enemy to move towards player.
So I am using Godot 3.3.4 and wrote this code, it should work. But it's not working.
I wrote this code in enemy script,
self.global_transform.origin.move_toward(player.global_transform.move_toward,32)

I feel like this should work because global_transform.origin is a vector. The "player" here has been in Onready var and the node is found.
I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Move_toward does not change the origin Vector3 directly, but returns a new Vector3 which moved towards the parameter by the delta amount.
So to actually move your enemy you have to set the global_transform.origin to the returned value:
global_transform.origin = global_transform.origin.move_toward(player.global_transform.origin, 32)

Note:
without knowing your code, but a delta of 32 might be way to fast.

omg thank you so much. I'm just training by myself, who would have known.
